# How to parse html in iOS to get all its content along with tag name?

Tags: ios, iphone

I was tried to parse html data using `TFHpple` as mentioned below

```
TFHpple *tutorialsParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:tutorialsHtmlData];
NSString *tutorialsXpathQueryString = @"//body";
NSArray *tutorialsNodes = [tutorialsParser searchWithXPathQuery:tutorialsXpathQueryString];
```

After done with above step I am getting tutorialsNodes array which contain all data.

I want to find each tag in it with its content.
I need tag to identified is it image or text etc.
I don't understand how to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
  ...
  for (TFHppleElement *element in tutorialsNodes)
  {
      [self handleElement:element];
  }
  ...
}

- (void)handleElement:(TFHppleElement *)element
{
    for (TFHppleElement *child in element.children) 
    {
        NSString *textInsideTheChildElement = child.content;

        if ([child.tagName isEqualToString:@"img"])
        {
            NSString *sourceUrl = child.attributes["src"];
        }
        else 
        {
            [self handleElement:child];
        }
    }
}
```